# VSCode crush after click on Accounts

Tags: github, click, restart, account, crush

Can someone help me with a recurring issue in Visual Studio Code? Whenever I click on "accounts", the program crashes and disappears without warning. I have to restart it every time this happens, regardless of how many times I run it. I've also noticed that this behavior occurs when I try to log in to online extensions like GitHub.

Comment: Please add screenshots.